# App store connect Error: ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist -

Tags: xcode

Getting this error in App store connect: Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely
.Not sure why.I 'm not using any of the two sdks: 1/ camera 2/ location. Can anyone let me know if i can generate my list in such a way to  remove these warnings.